# How build a serverless.yml file to deploy a http api + lambda project using serverless-express?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to replace the default sam-template from @vendia/serverless-express v2 example with a serverless.yml to deploy via serverless deploy

https://github.com/vendia/serverless-express/tree/mainline/examples/basic-starter-api-gateway-v2

How the serverless.yml will need to look like to deploy this httpApi example ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

a basic yml would look like this:

```html
service: lambda-project

provider:
    name: aws
    runtime: nodejs14.x
    stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
    memorySize: 256
    timeout: 10
    region: <REIGON>

package:
    individually: true

functions:
    func: #function name
        handler: func/func.handler #<PATH_TO_HANDLER>
        vpc:
            securityGroupIds:
                - sg-XXX
            subnetIds:
                - subnet-XXX
                - subnet-XXX
                - subnet-XXX
        events:
            - http:
                  path: /{any+} # if you want all the routes after / to go here if specific just write there
                  method: ANY
        package:
            include:
                - <path to the code directory>
```